# Why are the values for both dictionaries being updated, when I only want one updated? (Python OOP)

Tags: python, oop

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
class Document:
    def __init__(self):
        self.term_frequency_per_document = {}
        self.document_frequency = {}
        self.term_freq_inv_doc_freq = {}
        self.file = None
        self.student_list = []
        self.index = 0

    def calculate_TFIDF(self):

        for key in self.term_frequency_per_document:
            for value in self.term_frequency_per_document[key]:
                self.term_freq_inv_doc_freq[key] = self.term_frequency_per_document.get(key)
            for value in self.term_freq_inv_doc_freq[key]:
                self.term_freq_inv_doc_freq[key][value] = \
                    (self.term_freq_inv_doc_freq[key][value]) * \
                    (math.log(26 / float(self.document_frequency.get(value))))

        print (self.term_freq_inv_doc_freq)
        print (self.document_frequency)
        print (self.term_frequency_per_document)
```

When I execute the `calculate_TFDIF` method, the values of both the `self.term_frequency_per_document` and `self.term_freq_inv_per_doc` dictionaries are being updated, when I only want the latter dictionary's values updated. I know that the erroneous update is occurring in the `calculate_TFDIF` method, but I cannot figure out why.

The `term_frequency_per_document` dictionary should read:

```
{'student_1': {'love': 1, 'play': 2, 'watch': 1}, 'student_2': {'favorite': 2, 'hobby': 1}
```

After executing the `calculate_TFDIF` method, the `term_freq_inv_doc_freq` dictionary should read:

```
{'student_1': {'love': 1.6486586255873816, 'play': 2.121743921370525, 'watch': 1.8718021769015913} 'student_2': {'favorite': 1.9110228900548727, 'hobby': 1.1786549963416462}
```

Unfortunately, both dictionaries look like the latter.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. (Or at least make this more readable....)

Comment: use `print()` inside `for` loops to see what values you get and set - it can helps to find problem.

Comment: how do you create dictionares ? maybe you assign the same dictionary to two variables and than both variables use the same data in memory. You will have to use `copy.deepcopy()` to create two separated dictionares. You may run code on [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/) to see how Python use "references" to objects im memory (see "arrows" when you run code on pythontutor)

Comment: Thank you, @furas, the `copy.deepcopy()` function did the trick. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll gladly mark the question as solved by you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you assign the same dictionary to two variables and then both variables use the same data in memory. You will have to use [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) to create two separated dictionares.

BTW: You may run code on [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com) to see how Python use "references" to objects im memory (see "arrows" when you run code on pythontutor)